Distance between a data point and a cluster
My dataset has 400 rows and 14 columns. I take rows 1-100 of data and find clusters using pca and t-SNE. Now, I want to see if any of rows 101-200 lie within any of the clusters I have found for rows 1-100. How to do that?
The following figure shows the clusters obtained for rows 1-100.


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
